# Why is it a good programming practise to check whether a value exists before using it?

Tags: php

Suppose using a isset() function, we checked whether an ID  did exist or the user did submit an ID, before assigning it to variables or using it some place in the code that follows.

```
     <?php

        if(isset($_GET['Id']))
    {

     $Id=$_GET['Id'];
    }
?>
```

Now I understand, it's good to do this

1)So the code as per the expected behavior i.e. does what it's expected to accomplish. For Example -  if id was going to be used in some query which would return a row based on that id, it's always a good idea to provide a valid id to be sure that the query indeed returns a row as a result... This avoids the unexpected behavior that the query fails if it wasn't provided with a valid id.

2)And as obvious, minimizing any runtime errors that our code might generate.

So, I'm looking for more relevant examples and context as to why this is always a good programming practise.

Basically more examples to help me sink in my understanding why it's really good to do so ... Many Thanks.

Comment: you intelligent people who closed this question don't like helping someone reinforce a concept and become a better programmer... :)

Comment: a) your code has errors, b) you gave yourself answers in the question which makes the whole thing a bit odd

Comment: a)yes errors cos i just typed in some quick code but i don't think it hindered anyone in understanding what the question was all about... b)yes answered myself but was looking for approval on my understanding and/or further correction/improvement.

Comment: Just look at the answer preinheimer gave, it not only did help me in solidifying my understanding but also improved upon it by proving me a way to make it even better... Is getting help for writing good code not a purpose on stackoverflow ?

Comment: There just wasn't enough question in your question... it was on the verge but not quite there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the future.

If you simply stated `$id = $_GET['id']` and used the variable later on, your application may behave in an unexpected manner.

Say next week you come back and write some code that uses that convinenent `$id` variable. From glancing up in the file you see it used elsewhere and don't plan on it not being set. That code works when you test it quickly, but fails under real-world use. Maybe it errors out, maybe it spits out an admin page, maybe it explodes and kills puppies, *who knows?*

If you'd been a bit more careful, and done something like:

```
$id = 0; //default document
if (isset($_GET['id'])
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Your code would always have an `$id` to work with. Note the small addition there, I haven't simply ensured that `$_GET['id']` exists before I assign it's value to another variable, I've ensured that `$id` /always/ has a value.

If I was an ounce smarter, I'd probably do something like this instead: `if (isset($_GET['id'] && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) && isValidId($_GET['id']))`

Comment: -+1  Good answer... would have been great to see more examples/answers that would renforce someone's understanding and help him become a better programmer , if only the intelligent people who closed this question  would allow it...:)

Comment: Note, this is only useful in cases where you have a reasonable default.  In many cases, it's better to have no value at all than a valid-but-not-*really*-valid one.  (You can do the same thing using `null` in such cases, but it goes against the whole reasoning of this answer.)